# Rails 5: Using Capybara with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, passenger

I am trying to run specs on a Rails 5 app. However, I am seeing the following LoadError:

> Failure/Error: raise LoadError, 'Capybara is unable to load `puma` for
>   its server, please add `puma` to your project or specify a different
>   server via something like `Capybara.server = :webrick`.'

I am using the `passenger` gem for the production server. Is there a way in which I can use passenger for the Capybara tests as well?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a guess. `Capybara.server = :passenger` in your rails_helper? See: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#setup

Comment: That causes an error, `Failure/Error: Capybara.server.call(middleware, port, host), NoMethodError: undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass` so I think it's not a symbol I can pass to Capybara.server :(

Comment: Looks like puma is your only choice. Try adding it to the test group in your Gemfile. Might also have to move passenger into your production group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use passenger to run your app while testing you will need to startup your app separately with passenger using the rails test environment (so it uses the test DB, etc) and then set

```
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.app_host = "http://<wherever the app is accessible>"
```

for your tests. This tells Capybara not to bother with running the app itself and to just connect to the app you're already running. You will also need to use something like `database_cleaner` to handle database resetting between tests, and be very careful to make sure you don't have any leftover requests running at the end of each test.

When running the tests with `puma` or `webrick` none of that is required (database_cleaner is generally required for rails < 5.1 but not 5.1+), because the web server is run in the same process (different threads) as the tests which allows Capybara to know when requests are still being processed and for Rails to share the DB connection with the tests. Overall you're just going to have a much smoother experience if you stick with `puma` or `webrick` for your tests.

Comment: I've added passenger to the production group and just stuck with puma for dev & test. I'm surprised the passenger docs don't say to do this by default since it's essentially incompatible with standard Rails testing tools.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this:

The [capybara documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.register_server):

```
This block takes a rack app and a port and returns a 
rack server listening on that port
```

From the [passenger repo](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/778):

```
This is fundamentally incompatible with Phusion Passenger's model. 
Such a Rack handler implies a single application and a single process.
Phusion Passenger runs multiple processes which can even serve multiple 
applications.
```